# Laravel Trying to Store Cache Files in Root Folder

Tags: php, caching, laravel-5

I am getting the following error from Laravel5 upon rendering any page:

```
ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 74: 
file_put_contents(/fdcc73e2e72031a510ae8f921ce1d22d): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

my cache config is as follows:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default cache connection that gets used while
    | using this caching library. This connection is used when another is
    | not explicitly specified when executing a given caching function.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cache Stores
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the cache "stores" for your application as
    | well as their drivers. You may even define multiple stores for the
    | same cache driver to group types of items stored in your caches.
    |
    */

    'stores' => [

        'apc' => [
            'driver' => 'apc'
        ],

        'array' => [
            'driver' => 'array'
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table'  => 'cache',
            'connection' => null,
        ],

        'file' => [
            'driver' => 'file',
            'path'   => storage_path().'/framework/cache',
        ],

        'memcached' => [
            'driver'  => 'memcached',
            'servers' => [
                [
                    'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => 11211, 'weight' => 100
                ],
            ],
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cache Key Prefix
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When utilizing a RAM based store such as APC or Memcached, there might
    | be other applications utilizing the same cache. So, we'll specify a
    | value to get prefixed to all our keys so we can avoid collisions.
    |
    */

    'prefix' => 'laravel',

];
```

Interestingly enough if I change the default to array or any of the other options it still tries to write the cache file to root folder and fails every time.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: I'm facing similar problem, how did u solve it

Answer (score 20):

See if 'storage/framework/views' exists. If you add it and you still have problems. Make sure it is writeable (775, 77, etc...)

In my case, error happened because I deployed to my production server via github, but the contents of storage were not tracked by git. I fixed this by making sure that the .gitignore files in each of the directories inside /storage were committed to the repo.

**Notes:** 
Usually those weird filenames have something to do with the Blade templates. I don't think it's actually trying to store the cache file in root.

My error was similar: "ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 81: file_put_contents(/f946048111f1176619e22f5127724e37): failed to open stream: Permission denied"

Comment: This worked for me as well. I did not publish through git, but for some reason the `storage/framework/` directories were not present. Creating and setting to 775 fixed it for me: `storage/framework/cache`, `storage/framework/sessions`, and `storage/framework/views`

Comment: I had the same error but the root cause was because git does not store empty directories. 

So I had to create: 
`/storage/logs`, 
`/storage/framework/cache`, 
`/storage/framework/sessions`, 
`/storage/framework/views`

and add .gitignore files to all of those directories with these contents:
    # ignore everything except .gitignore
    *
    !.gitignore

Comment: Thank you sir. I spent a day trying to figure this out. The weird thing is if you were to do the very wrong thing of giving permissions to the root dir, it would work and store in the root dir! Why couldn't they just have told us no directory found in storage/framework/view...

Answer (score 9):

I am using debian 7 wheezy.

If you are getting these type of errors, Do these steps

Go to the app folder (ex : /home/app/web)

1. **php artisan config:cache**
2. **php artisan cache:clear**
3. **php artisan view:clear**
4. **chmod -R 777 storage/  or chown -R webuser:webuser storage/**
5. **chmod -R 777 public/   or chown -R webuser:webuser public/**
6. **service apache2 reload,service apache2 restart**

Note: Webuser here refers to www-data or customised user

Please make sure that the database is connected with the page.

Comment: on OSX (At least, from El Capitan) webuser is `www`.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you loading the **CACHE_DRIVER** from?

The line

`'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),`

is looking either for your system environment variables and for the **.env** file located at the root of your project. By the away that you describe, I'm assuming you are only trying to change the cache method at the cache config file. The second parameter of the method is a 'default' value in case laravel does not find the **CACHE_DRIVER** elsewhere.

You should check the file **.env** on the root of project for the variable **CACHE_DRIVER**. If it is there, the value will have priority over the configuration at the `cache.php`.

---

Another solution would be to make sure that laravel has writing permission at the specified directory. See if the folder has the permission of writing either for the `www-data` user or group (at least).